# Get the key from a dictionary object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist

I have a dictionary set up like the one below. How can I get the actual key value (the actor's name) from `objectAtIndex:1`?

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Brad Pitt</key>
    <array>
        <string>Fight Club</string>
        <string>Seven</string>
        <string>Inglorious Basterds</string>
        <string>Babel</string>
    </array>
    <key>Meryl Streep</key>
    <array>
        <string>Adaptation</string>
        <string>The Devil Wears Prada</string>
        <string>Doubt</string>
        <string>Julie &amp; Julia</string>
    </array>
    <key>Chris Cooper</key>
    <array>
        <string>Adaptation</string>
        <string>American Beauty</string>
        <string>The Bourne Identity</string>
        <string>October Sky</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this?

```
NSString *actorName = [[actorsDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: This is deceptively wrong.  `allKeys` returns things in an **undefined** order (because the dictionary itself is unordered).  While internal implementation details may return a seemingly consistent ordering, *this may change and has changed in the past*.  Relying on this behavior would be flat-out wrong.

Comment: Dave it would be great if you offered an alternative because nobody else has.

Answer (score 5):

Brute force it:

```
- (NSString *)actorForFilm:(NSString *)film {
    NSDictionary * dictionary = ...; //your dictionary as read from the plist
    for (NSString * actorName in dictionary) {
        NSArray * films = [dictionary objectForKey:actorName];
        if ([films containsObject:film]) {
            return actorName;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

If you want to return a random key from the dictionary, you could do:

```
NSArray * allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
NSString * randomKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:(arc4random() % [allKeys count])];
```

Comment: I won't know any film or actor's name in advance. All I will have is a random object index number.

Comment: Then an NSDictionary is the wrong data structure for you, since it is, by definition, unordered.  You need an ordered map, and AFAIK, Foundation and AppKit don't include one, so...

Comment: Or better yet, is there a way to simply return a random key?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries aren't ordered, so there is no `objectAtIndex:` method in the `NSDictionary` class. If you want to store the actor/film pairs in an ordered list you need to store them in an NSArray, for example using a structure like this:

```
# pseudo-code: [] = array, {} = dictionary
[
    { actor: "Brad Pitt", movies: ["Fight Club", "Seven", "Babel"] },
    { actor: "Meryl Streep", movies: ["Adaptation", "Doubt"] },
    # etc...
]
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know that dictionaries were unordered, so that would make sense. However, for other reasons, I am avoiding structuring my data that way. Is it possible to load the key values of the dictionary into an array first, and then grab the actor's name based on an index value?

Comment: Using an index key will work. But you will still be using the wrong data structure. Depending on what you are working on you may want to avoid that technical dept. Using the wrong data structure is an easy way to rack up "quick fixes" that degrade your code base.